# Return value of catch in promises?

Tags: javascript

The MDN documentation for [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) indicates the return value of a function is "a promise".

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success');
});
p1.then(function(value) {
  throw 'oh, no!';
}).catch(function(e) {
  return "some other value";  // where does this go?
})
```

Does a return within a catch block have any effect, i.e. is it passed along as a resolved Promise available to other then blocks?

Comment: Did you try putting `.then` after `.catch` block and seeing what happens or are you just wondering?

Comment: You aren't `resolve`-ing or `reject`-ing so my guess would be the promise wouldn't terminate.